# Can't play rtsp stream from IP Camera using VideoView

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-videoview, rtsp

I've seen a few resembling questions but no solution so I'll share my own specific problem:

I am writing an app that is supposed to play a live video stream from an IP Camera. I'm using a VideoView but also tried a MediaPlayer and an Intent with no luck - the live stream is not played.

Using a VideoView I successfully play other streams, for example:
rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov

But with my IP Camera stream I get a popup dialog: "Can't play this video" and a FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://.../videoMain

The stream is played well in VLC. The video codec is H264 MPEG-4 AVC. I'm using Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 5.1.1. I get the same results with different Emulators though.

My code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_camera);
        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
        String vidAddress = "rtsp://<user>:<pass>@...:88/videoMain";


        Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
        vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

        vidView.start();
    }
```

Also added permissions to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Any idea of how to make the stream play, or a reason for not being able to play it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, @Veener, never found. Using ffmpeg.